# How eliminate recursion in Python to solve RuntimeError?

Tags: python, recursion

I run my code with recursion code, but it appear the below error:

`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

my code like this:

```
def comp_ele(old, new):
    res = None
    if isinstance(old, dict):
        res = comp_dict(old, new)
    elif isinstance(old, list):
        res = comp_arr(old, new)
    else:
        pass
    return res

def comp_arr(old_arr, new_arr):
    i = min(len(old_arr), len(new_arr))
    result = {u'a':{}, u'u':{}, u'r':{}}
    for index in xrange(i):
        res = comp_ele(old_arr[index], new_arr[index])
        if res is not None:
            result[u'u'][index] = res

    # ...

    return result

def comp_dict(old_obj, new_obj):
    # like comp_arr
    # ...
    result = {u'a':{}, u'u':{}, u'r':{}}
    #...
    result = comp_ele(old_obj[index], new_obj[index])
    #...
    return result
```

I have use this but not solve:

`sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)`

So, I should update `recursion` to `while` for solve runtimeerror, but how do I should do? Use `itertools`?

Comment: Are you sure your program isn't buggy? Does it return the correct answer with smaller inputs?

Comment: A short explanation of what your code is supposed to, or generally what you have and what you want to achieve? Irrelevant to the question, but you have a duplicated key in your dictionaries, `{u'a':{}, u'a':{}, u'r':{}}`.

Comment: Got some mutual recursion going on. Can you construct a test case to ensure it will terminate ?

Comment: @JulienBernu I input some simple data, it is OK, if some nests is error. This code is simple code, not whole code.

Comment: @paisanco OK, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I have solved the problem. this reason is infinite loop in the one case.